# For any positive integer n, find the range of the product 1∗3∗5∗7∗9∗…∗(2n−1) in terms of n.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, number-theory

For any positive integer $n$, find the range of the product $1*3*5*7*9* \ldots *(2n-1)$ in terms of $n$.

I have posted my answer...

Comment: The question is not clear. The tagging seems inappropriate --- if you are using an integral, the problem can't be precalculus. Also, didn't you post this question some time ago?

Comment: the product $=\frac{(2n)!}{n!2^n}$ then can we use  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: Multiply and divide by 2 * 4 * 6 * 8 * ...* (2n). The numerator is then (2n)! and now work the denominator. So you will arrive to what lab bhattacharjee mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally arrived at a solution:

Let $I_k$ = $\int_{2k-1}^{2k+1}\ln x\ \rm dx$

2ln(2k-1) < $I_k$ <2ln(2k+1)

Adding such terms, we get

$\int_{1}^{2k+1}\ln x\ \rm dx$ < 2(ln3+ln5+...+ln(2n-1))............(1)

and  2(ln3+ln5+...+ln(2n-1)) < $\int_{3}^{2k+1}\ln x\ \rm dx$ ......(2)

Knowing that integral(lnx dx)=xlnx+c

From 1 and 2 we conclude that

1∗3∗5∗7∗9∗…∗(2n−1) < (2n+1/e)^((2n+1)/2)
and   1∗3∗5∗7∗9∗…∗(2n−1) > (2n-1/e)^((2n-1)/2)

which are the required bounds.

I hope my solution is correct...